# Jump to MSDN docs from VS

Tags: visual-studio-2008, plugins, documentation

Say I have this line:

```
Foo = reader.ReadElementContentAsInt();
```

I want to rightclick "ReadElementContentAsInt" and select some kind of "Jump to MSDN" option that opens the documentation in my browser.

If it's easily extensible to work with other lib docs (e.g. Qt), even better.

Do I need a VS plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using VS2010 and selected Online Help in help settings this will be default action on F1.